# Add a parent member to a JSON data

Tags: java, json, web-services

I'm having a REST web service that produces a JSON format output from an ArrayList of custom type.

```
@GET()
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("/ratings")
public List<Rating> getRatings( ) {
Rating rating;
List<Rating> ratings = new ArrayList<Rating>();
rating= new Rating();
//here I set rating object
rating.setNote(...);
// etc....
ratings.add(rating);

//the method returns ratings arraylist
return ratings;
```

I want to add a parent member to all JSON data like this:

```
{"ratings":[{"a":"1","b":"test"}]}
```

and not like:

```
[{"a":"1","b":"test"}]
```

Can I do that?
Thanks for helping.

Comment: JSON can be any combo of arrays and "objects" that you want.

Comment: Well, you can ... sure. Why you'd want to is another question. Create an object that has a field `ratings` that is your `ArrayList<Rating>` and return that instead.

Comment: @BrianRoach: That's really a long story why I have to output JSON file like that :D, anyway, can you help me please?

Comment: I just did. See the edit. You need a class that resembles that JSON if that's what you want to return and have (I'm assuming Jersy) serialize it to JSON for you.

Comment: Create a class that contains a field `ratings`, make an instance of the class, set its field to the list you create and populate, and then return that instance.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis: That's a good idea, however, I think the web service converts an object to a JSON format just when invoking it, not in the object itself.

Comment: @androniennn Jersey uses Jackson iirc with the `@Produces(json)` annotation, which uses reflection to convert your object to json. It'll see the Class you make has a field `ratings` which is a list so it'll convert it to `{"ratings":[{"a":"1","b":"test}]}` if ratings is a list and contains one element.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Ah okay that's clear. Jersey is to convert any object to json format. But I don't know why replacing `@Produces("application/json")``by `@Produces(json)`?

Comment: I was just typing fast, you have the right annotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON you're asking for is an object that contains a single field (`ratings`) that is an array or your `Rating` objects. Provided you have POJO JSON support enabled which it seems you do, that's what you have to return if that's what you want.

```
@XmlRootElement
class Response {
    public final List<Rating> ratings;

    public Resonse(List<Rating> ratings) {
        this.ratings = ratings;
    }
}
```

Change your method signature to return an instance of `Response` then:

```
return new Reponse(ratings);
```

There's a fairly extensive guide found [here](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/json.html)

Option B is simply doing the JSON serialization yourself and returning a `String` (the JSON).

Comment: Sorry but where the add of the `{"Ratings":` string is added ?

Comment: You seem not to be grasping what JSON is, or represents. The first paragraph of my answer explains what you're asking for. JSON serialization is going to take that class and serialize it; the field is named `ratings`. It may require a provider though, looking up the info in the docs.

Comment: ratings does not contain a single field in my case, it has almost 100 fields on it, I just posted an example to explain. For JSON output `@Produces("application/json")` make all the work, I have all entries in a well formed json format in browser, what it lacks, is the add of parent member.

Comment: the JSON you show is an object with a single field `ratings` which has *an array* as its value. Which again, is exactly what the above provides once serialized to JSON. Unless the JSON you have shown is not what you want, in which case I'm not sure how anyone can answer that.

Comment: I re-read all your answers with attention, and it's really working! Nice trick, that was a misunderstood from me. Thank you very much. Accepted ;)!

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to continue to use Jersey's direct object mapping feature, then yes - creating an object that holds the list of "Ratings" is the best way to go.

Otherwise, you can create a custom serializer. See [this example](http://blog.palominolabs.com/2012/06/05/writing-a-custom-jackson-serializer-and-deserializer/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
@Provider
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class XJsonBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<Object> {
    // implement methods
    public void writeTo(Object obj, Class<?> clazz, Type type,
        Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> map, OutputStream out)
        throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        // serialize it how you want
    }
}
```